# ASP.NET MVC: Automapper e NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, automapper

Boa noite,
estou com um problema.
Estou usando o nHibernate para conexão com meu banco de dados e utilizo tambem o Automapper para mapear minhas Entidades para minha ViewModel.

Porém quando seleciono a entidade tenho varios relacionamentos e quando mapeio para a ViewModel acaba que todos as entidades filhos estão sendo mapeadas:

```
public ActionResult Cadastro(int id){
    Briefing bf = _briefingAppService.Get(id);

    BriefingModel model = BriefingModel.GetModel(this);

    BriefingViewModel viewModel = BriefingViewModel.ToViewModel(bf);

    return View(viewModel);
```

Meu Mapeamento está assim:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Briefing, BriefingViewModel>();
```

E esse é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]    }

Mas eu tenho varios relacionamentos nessa classe, e essa quantidade está deixando meu sistema muito lento.

Alguem sabe o que posso fazer para o Automapper nao mapear todos esses registros para minha ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Exemplos:***

*Existem duas formas e são elas:*

***1) Primeira forma***

Nessas duas classes People e Phone (1 pessoa pode ter vários telefones),

```
public class People
{
    public People()
    {
        Phone = new HashSet<Phone>();
    }
    public People(int id, string name, DateTime? datenasc)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        DateNasc = datenasc;
        Phone = new HashSet<Phone>();
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateNasc { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Phone> Phone { get; set; }
}
public class Phone
{
    public Phone() { }
    public Phone(int id, string ddd, string number, People people)
    {
        Id = id;
        Ddd = ddd;
        Number = number;
        People = people;
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Ddd { get; set; }
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual People People { get; set; }
}
```

eu não quero que o [Automapper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) traga a lista de telefones de pessoas e ai minha classe de recebimento ficará assim:

```
public class PeopleView
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateNasc { get; set; }
}
```

Ou seja, ela não tem a lista de telefone e por isso o [Automapper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) só vai trazer o que eu defini na *classe* `PeopleView`.

***Como usar:***

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(People), typeof(PeopleView));
PeopleView peopleView = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PeopleView>(people);

//COLEÇÃO
List<People> Pessoas = con.ToList<People>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(People), typeof(PeopleView)); 
var peoplesview = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<People>, List<PeopleView>>(Pessoas);
```

***Debugando:***

*Dados de uma classe*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Dados de uma coleção*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***2) Segunda forma***

Você também pode criar uma regra no [Automapper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) falando para ele **ignorar** a lista ou listas, seguindo o exemplo da *classe People* mais a alteração colocado logo abaixo:

```
public class PeopleView
{
    public PeopleView()
    {
        Phone = new HashSet<Phone>();
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateNasc { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Phone> Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Configurando o [Automapper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/)

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(People), typeof(PeopleView))
                .ForMember("Phone", x => x.Ignore());
```

Automaticamente ele vai ignorar a lista de telefones como demostrado na imagem logo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Demo*

https://dotnetfiddle.net/99Zqlf

*Referencias:*

- [Ignore mapping one property with Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988159)
- [AutoMapper 4.0.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/)

Comment: Cezar, vou fazer isso que que você falou e ver como vai ficar aqui. Assim que eu modificar eu ja posto se deu certo.

Comment: Cezar, Desculpa a demora para responder kkk, tava realizando os testes. Deu certinho... Vou continuar a aplicação e se mais para frente eu me deparar com outro problema eu aviso. Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda.